# Issue with Jmeter launching

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I am having an issue while launching the Jmeter. I successfully installed Java in my machine and even I installed Jmeter in my system but when I clicked on Jmeter.bat file noting pops up. I have Java 9.0 version running in my laptop.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVYpk.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Looking into error you're getting my expectation is that your problem is caused by <strike>ugly and shitty</strike> [more attractive](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61697) Darkula Look and Feel theme.

I would recommend trying to launch JMeter in normal "light" mode as:

- Delete the following registry key using [registry editor](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-open-registry-editor-2625150)

  ```
  Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\JavaSoft\Prefs\org\apache\jmeter
  ```
- Launch JMeter as follows:

  ```
  java -jar ApacheJMeter.jar -Jjmeter.laf=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel
  ```
- If it helps you can make the change permanent by adding the next line to *user.properties* file

  ```
  jmeter.laf=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel
  ```

More information:

- [Look and Feel configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#laf_config)
- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

---

If you still want to use JMeter in "dark mode" you will have to install [Java 8](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) as it appears there is a [bug in the dark theme](https://github.com/bulenkov/Darcula/issues/41).